# How to log into an Extreme Networks Summit 200-24?

Tags: switch

I have received a Summit 200-24 from a friend to help host a small LAN party this weekend. However having never used a managed switch before, I have no clue how to log into it. It has a console port on the side but I have to computer that has one of those ports.

It doesn't appear to have an IP address on my network, so I cannot for the life of me find its IP address to see if I can log into it from a browser.

If anyone can tell me how I can log into this switch that would be great!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need a console cable, a serial port on your PC, and a terminal application.

It is all explained in [Summit 200 Series Switch Installation and User Guide](http://extrcdn.extremenetworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/Summit200User.pdf):

> ### Accessing the BootROM menu
>
> Interaction with the BootROM menu is only required under special
>   circumstances, and should be done only under the direction of Extreme
>   Networks Customer Support. The necessity of using these functions
>   implies a non-standard problem which requires the assistance of
>   Extreme Networks Customer Support.
>
> To access the BootROM menu, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Attach a serial cable to the console port of the switch.
> 2. Attach the other end of the serial cable to a properly configured
>      terminal or terminal emulator, power cycle the switch while
>      depressing the spacebar on the keyboard of the terminal.
>
>    As soon as you see the `BootROM->` prompt, release the spacebar. You
>      can see a simple help menu by pressing `h`. Options in the menu
>      include
>
>    — Selecting the image to boot from
>
>    — Booting to factory default configuration
>
> For example, to change the image that the switch boots from in flash
>   memory, press `1` for the image stored in primary or `2` for the image
>   stored in secondary. Then, press the `f` key to boot from newly
>   selected on-board flash memory.
>
> To boot to factory default configuration, press the `d` key for
>   default and the `f` key to boot from the configured on-board flash.

Comment: So there is no way to log in over a network then.

Comment: Not unless you already have the information in the switch configuration. You would need to know how the switch is configured, including the management IP address, which ports are in which VLANs, etc.